# postman returning "status": 404, "error": "Not Found", for the spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Thank you in advance, Hello I am new to spring boot. I am facing a problem with spring boot. When I run my URL in postman it shows an error below. I have also uploaded my code below. I don't find any idea what wrong with my code.

```
 {
    "timestamp": "2021-07-09T06:43:57.429+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/todo"
}
```

[image: My project structure]

Controller code
This is a code for my controller code.

```
package com.assignment.todo.Todo.Controller;
import com.assignment.todo.Todo.Repo.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.assignment.todo.Todo.Model.*;
import com.assignment.todo.Todo.Repo.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/todo")
public class TodoController  {

@Autowired
private TodoRepo todoRepo;

@GetMapping
public List<TodoModel> findAll(){
    return todoRepo.findAll();
    
}
    
@PostMapping
public TodoModel save(@Valid @NotNull @RequestBody TodoModel todoItem) {
    return todoRepo.save(todoItem);
    
}

}
```

Model

code for my model class
package com.assignment.todo.Todo.Model;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
@Entity
public class TodoModel {
    
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String title;
    private boolean done;
    
    public TodoModel() {
        
    }
    
    public TodoModel(long id, String title, boolean done) {
        this.id=id;
        this.title=title;
        this.done=done;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }

    
    

}
```

Repo
code for my repo class

```
package com.assignment.todo.Todo.Repo;
import com.assignment.todo.Todo.Model.*;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;



public interface TodoRepo extends JpaRepository<TodoModel, Long> {

}
```

MainClass

```
package com.assignment.todo.Todo;
import com.assignment.todo.Todo.Controller.*;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import com.assignment.todo.Todo.Repo.*;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "TodoRepo.java")
public class TodoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodoApplication.class, args);
        
    }

}
```

pom.xml
My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.assignment.todo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Todo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Todo</name>
    <description>Assignment in Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
             <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
          <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepositosry.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/maven-istack-commons-plugin -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/maven-istack-commons-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.istack</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-istack-commons-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: try removing `scanBasePackages = "TodoRepo.java"` from main class

Comment: Packaging no issue all class belong to within one package.

Comment: this is my URL http://localhost:8000/todo which I have used in postman

Comment: Can you please let us know what is the URL you are providing in postman along with the application.properties file. Also for scanBasePackages we don't provide a class name we provide a package name as the name says, so provide a appropriate package name under which all classes are present so that it can be scanned by Spring during startup, here com.assignment.todo

Comment: After adding this line it still show the same error @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.assignment.todo.Todo.Controller.TodoController")

Comment: Just add @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.assignment.todo")
Please share the application.yaml or application.properties whichever is present under resources folder

Comment: application.properties file in empty

Comment: Add server.port=8080 in application.properties file then make the request from postman using URL http://localhost:8080/todo, as you have only get and post request in controller make sure you don't make any other type of request via the postman.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What is the command your using to build and start the service? Is there error messages on startup logs?

Comment: No, the build was successful

Answer (score 1):

```
@RestController("/todo")// you can give any URL here
public class TodoController  {

@Autowired
private TodoRepo todoRepo;

@GetMapping("/getAll")// you can give any URL here
public List<TodoModel> findAll(){
    return todoRepo.findAll();
    
}
    
@PostMapping("/save")// you can give any URL here
public TodoModel save(@Valid @NotNull @RequestBody TodoModel todoItem) {
    todoRepo.save(todoItem);
    return todoItem;
}
}
```

you give the mapping to the method like this. you can give any URL name. This is the main reason you get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in your mapping. You didn't specify the mapping path so findAll and save has default mapping as empty then controller could not understand which API you calling. Add below things and try.

```
@GetMapping(value="/findAll")

@PostMapping(value=/save")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but after making change it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but after making a change it still doesn't work. Here is my code after edit RestController
RequestMapping(value="/todo")
public class TodoController  {

Autowired
private TodoRepo todoRepo;

GetMapping(value="/findAll")
public List<TodoModel> findAll(){
 return todoRepo.findAll();
 
}
 
PostMapping(value="/save")
public TodoModel save(Valid NotNull @RequestBody TodoModel todoItem) {
 return todoRepo.save(todoItem);
 
}

}

Comment: May be you have cross origin problem.

Comment: @CrossOrigin on controller level.

Comment: If not work then try to add in method level as @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")

Comment: still not working after updating code to RestController
CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
RequestMapping(value="/todo")
public class TodoController  {}

Comment: Still 404 exact same issue?

Comment: "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/todo"  error

Comment: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages ="com.assignment.todo.Todo")

Comment: Base scan package should like above.

Answer (score 0):

The TodoApplication class must be above this one level.

change this:

from

```
package com.assignment.todo.Todo;
```

to

```
package com.assignment.todo;
```